# Django CSS Site Wide Static Files

Tags: css, django

I am struggling to get css to work globally across my Django project.

I have a STATICFILES_DIRS called 'project_static' with a css file in it.
This is in the root of my project.
In my settings.py I have:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
'/Users/gavinhinfey/django_projects/ss_stream/project_static/',
)
```

In base.html I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/main.css">

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The css file links fine when I'm at a page template within an app 'stream' which I have created. However when I'm viewing a page template not specific to an app it does not see the css.

Any idea why this is?

I've done my best to explain this but if you need clarification on the problem please ask.

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: What is the value of STATIC_URL ?

Comment: `code` STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: You could view the generated code with your browser to see if the `href` is correct.

Comment: Also check that you have `django.core.context_processors.static` under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: And what is the value of STATIC_ROOT ? Have you done a `manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: @SteveK `collectstatic` shouldn't be needed until deployment if he's working with `runserver`.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = ''. I have not done a manage.py collectstatic.

Comment: Adrian:
In the browser the broken link to the CSS is: 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/css/main.css'

The working link is:
'http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css'

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I've just discovered that they added STATICFILES_FINDERS in Django 1.5. It's a whole world I have to delve into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{STATIC_URL}}` has been deprecated (I think) so it's probably rendering `css/main.css` only.

I suggest you configure it as follows:

**settings.py**

```
import os.path

PWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # project root path

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PWD + '/static/',  # or project_static, whatever
)
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

This way you can use relative paths in your settings, and avoid breaking the settings if you move your whole project outside of your home directory.

You can use it for every path setting, such as `LOCALE_PATHS` or `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

If this doesn't work yet check that you have these settings:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# optional but if you defined it be sure to have this one:
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I tried this and got a 
`code`Invalid block tag: 'static'`code`
on base.html

Comment: @GavinHinfey yeah that's cause I forgot the `{% load static %}`

Comment: @ Adrian
humm, now the css is not working at all...

Does it have anything to do with this?
In the browser the broken CSS link is: 'localhost:8000/accounts/login/css/main.css'; 
The working link is: 
'localhost:8000/static/css/main.css';

Comment: @GavinHinfey So the static tag is not working. I assume you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` under `INSTALLED_APPS`, is that right?

Comment: Ye I do. I'm sure its me being an idiot. Let me spend a bit more time trying it.

Comment: Do I need the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS?

Comment: @GavinHinfey shouldn't be needed if you didn't define it in your `settings.py`. The default value includes `'django.core.context_processors.static'`.

Comment: That fixed it your a FLIPPIN LEGEND

Answer (score 0):

Note that STATICFILES_DIRS is an interable with directories where to find static files for the project.
But the app should not look for files in the same folder. It should look for files in STATIC_ROOT (which is different). Your resource files will be in STATIC_ROOT only after a `manage.py collectstatic`